# Can my reducer's output key type be different than input?

Tags: mapreduce, text-formatting, reducers

Actually my key to reducer is custom key (word1, word2) and I want to write output, in format like "word1\tword2" . And I'm not able to do that.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: there was already \t between pair... I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting
try this

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  CustomKey customkey = (CustomKey) key;

  context.write(new Text(customkey.word1+"/"+customkey.word2), result);
}
```

Comment: thanks @zuxqoj, I think my Write method of WritableComparable did this! but thanks for reply!